# Selenium JS : Change tab in devtools panel

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to test a chrome extension in selenium.

The goal of the extension is to test a website. It devtool panel needs to be opened at the same time as the tested website (open the .html of the extension in a new page won't work).

For now, i install the extension using it .crx, and i open automatically the devtools panel for tabs. I have to change to switch to the extension panel. I wanted to use the shortcut to do it, but i crashes, as i'm not typing in any text box (i think).

```
           await sleep(1000)
           await driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
           await sleep(1000)
           let actions = new Actions(driver)
           await actions
               .keyDown(Key.COMMAND)
               .sendKeys("[")
               .keyUp(Key.COMMAND)
               .perform();
```

Here's the error i'm getting : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'COMMAND')`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's no way to do this with webdriver or cdp (that I'm aware of) But maybe the autoit people can help you.

Comment: @pguardiario, i'd like to built the test server-side, so it won't work like this.. Thanks anyway !